# FTP downloaded data contains literal unicode such as \x00 and \n

Tags: python, parsing, ftp

I'm currently pulling from an FTP server to run a parser on a group of files when parsing the file from downloading in-browser and feeding the file into the parser, I get no errors since it's a plain TXT file.

But, when I pull the data from the server through Python's `ftplib`, I get differently formatted data. An example is the extra `\x00` and `'b'` characters inside my data. It's important that the data has integrity since I'm working with a COBOL database structure which can't be manipulated in the slightest else it will ruin the entire store.

I am successfully downloading using the following functions:

```py
data = []
def handle_binary(more_data):
    data.append(str(more_data))

def get_file(filename):
    resp = ftp.retrbinary("RETR {0}".format(filename), callback=handle_binary)
    file = "".join(data)
    # returning the data as well as saving it to inspect
    save = open("save.txt", "w+")
    save.write(file)
    save.close()
    return file
```

I tried to change my store from:

```
data.append(str(more_data))
```

To

```
data.append(more_data)
```

As well as changing my join function to be `b""` to indicate a byte join, but I got errors following that.

An example of a long string of data that wasn't in the original download:

```
\x00\x00\x00'b'\x00\n
```

Edit: Upon comparison, it seems that the FTP-downloaded data has no newlines (which makes sense since there's a missed newline in the above) as the downloaded copy does.

Thanks for any help regarding this question.

Comment: You need to use bytes consistently all the way through.  So as well as removing the `str(data)` and doing `b''.join` the file must be opened in _binary_ mode `'wb+'`.  If there are still problems after this, please provide the _complete_ traceback including the _exact_ error message.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb I'll try to apply this :)